# I've deleted Epiphany and I don't know how to get it back

Tags: web-browser

I've tried finding it on Github or App Center however I didn't. Is there any way to reinstall Epiphany?

Answer (score 3):

You can go to appCenter search "epiphany" and download it again. Or, in terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
```

[image]